# Getting AuthorizationFailed error while attempting to purge Azure CDN cache for particular content file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, azure-cdn

I am trying to generate a token and purge the Azure CDN cache for a particular content file. I am able to generate the token successfully but I am always getting below error

```
{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action' over scope '/subscriptions/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/resourcegroups/NONPRD-SEA/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/devmaritimeinfoportal/endpoints/devmaritimeinfoportal' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}
```

When I try the same thing with from [Try it editor here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cdn/endpoints/purge-content?tabs=HTTP) it is successfull.

Here is my code

```
        string clientId = ManagerConfig.AAD_ClientId;
        string clientSecret = ManagerConfig.AAD_ClientSecret;
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+ManagerConfig.AAD_TenantId);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        Task<AuthenticationResult> resultstr = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential);

        string apiResponse = string.Empty;
        string bearerToken = resultstr.Result.AccessToken;
        string fileCachePurgeRequestUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/resourcegroups/NONPRD-SEA/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/devmaritimeinfoportal/endpoints/devmaritimeinfoportal/purge?api-version=2023-05-01";
        var RequestBody = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            {"contentPaths",filePaths}
        };
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RequestBody);
        var contentData = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync(fileCachePurgeRequestUrl, contentData);
        apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Here is my list of permissions for the token requesting app in azure

[image: Permissions]

What am I missing here ? Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if your service principal does not have
> required **roles** or **permissions** to perform the operation.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried to purge the Azure CDN cache by calling below API, I too got **same error** like this:

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/profile1/endpoints/endpoint1/purge?api-version=2023-05-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
  "contentPaths": [
    "/folder1"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to assign **CDN Endpoint Contributor** role to the service principal at required scope as it has this permission in it
> `Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/endpoints/purge/action`  .

In my case, I assigned **CDN Endpoint Contributor** role to the service principal under resource group scope like below:

[image]

After assigning the role, I ran below API call by generating access token again and got **response** successfully like this:

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/profile1/endpoints/endpoint1/purge?api-version=2023-05-01
Authorization: Bearer <token>

{
  "contentPaths": [
    "/folder1"
  ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to assign **CDN Endpoint Contributor** role to the service principal under required scope.

**Reference:**
[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#cdn-endpoint-contributor)

Comment: The image links seem broken. @Sridevi Can you please edit ?

Comment: Could you please try accessing the same from different network or mobile device?

Comment: Thanks . It worked ! I had to give CDN Profile Contributor role to my CDN Host profile